# To convert upper case to lower case of same word in qbasic

Tags: basic, qbasic, qb64

Hi there i want to get idea or code for converting uppercase into lowercase and lowercase into uppercase of same word for eg: convert StAcKOVERfloW to sTaCkoverFLOw please can any one give me idea or the code for qbasic programming language

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.". It is also nice to state that this is a homework question. You can also check this link: http://www.qbasic.net/

Comment: If you have one string containing all uppercase letters and another string containing lowercase letters, you can use `INSTR` with those two strings to determine whether a character in your input string is uppercase or lowercase and convert it appropriately. Remember that you might have something other than letters in the string, and they should not be converted at all. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The way to solve this task is to process the characters in the string one after the other. A basic `FOR` `NEXT` loop accomplishes this:

```
FOR cpos% = 1 TO LEN(text$)
  char$ = MID$(text$, cpos%, 1)  ' Extracts 1 character at the current position
  ...
NEXT
```

QBasic has the `UCASE` and `LCASE` functions that will convert their string argument into uppercase and lowercase respectively. If the string we deal with consists of **a single word with nothing but uppercase and lowercase characters**, next code snippet will produce the desired result:

```
text$ = "StAcKOVERfloW"
PRINT text$;
FOR cpos% = 1 TO LEN(text$)
  char$ = MID$(text$, cpos%, 1)
  IF char$ >= "A" AND char$ <= "Z" THEN
    MID$(text$, cpos%) = LCASE$(char$)
  ELSE
    MID$(text$, cpos%) = UCASE$(char$)
  END IF
NEXT
PRINT " --> "; text$
```

We can write the above code without using `UCASE` or `LCASE`. Then we will be dealing with the ASCII codes of the characters. The uppercase characters "A" to "Z" have ASCII codes 65 to 90, and the lowercase characters "a" to "z" have ASCII codes 97 to 122. These ranges are 32 apart and that's an important number for the conversion from one in the other.
Next version works this way:

```
text$ = "StAcKOVERfloW"
PRINT text$;
FOR cpos% = 1 TO LEN(text$)
  char$ = MID$(text$, cpos%, 1)
  IF char$ >= "A" AND char$ <= "Z" THEN
    MID$(text$, cpos%) = CHR$(ASC(char$) + 32) ' Upper to Lower means + 32
  ELSE
    MID$(text$, cpos%) = CHR$(ASC(char$) - 32) ' Lower to Upper means - 32
  END IF
NEXT
PRINT " --> "; text$
```

This move to using the ASCII code will allow us to write the conversion in a single line. It's the `XOR` operator that does the heavy lifting here. We no longer need to decide about adding 32 or subtracting 32. The exclusive OR does the toggle for us:

```
text$ = "StAcKOVERfloW"
PRINT text$;
FOR cpos% = 1 TO LEN(text$)
  MID$(text$, cpos%) = CHR$(ASC(MID$(text$, cpos%, 1)) XOR 32)
NEXT
PRINT " --> "; text$
```

---

For a general solution to the problem of toggling the case of characters, we have to take into consideration that the user at the keyboard could be inputting an **empty** text, and that the text could turn out to contain **characters that are not uppercase or lowercase letters**.
To guard against an empty text, we can replace `FOR` `NEXT` by `WHILE` `WEND` where the condition is such that the loop is skipped if the current position *cpos%* does not exist in the string *text$*.
Because all modification to the string happens conditionally, there's no danger of modifying anything else than letters.

```
INPUT ; "Text : ", text$
cpos% = 1
WHILE cpos% <= LEN(text$)
  ascii% = ASC(MID$(text$, cpos%, 1))
  ucase% = ascii% AND &HDF
  IF ucase% >= 65 AND ucase% <= 90 THEN
    MID$(text$, cpos%) = CHR$(ascii% XOR 32)
  END IF
  cpos% = cpos% + 1
WEND
PRINT " --> "; text$
```

The code is 'optimized' in the way that it favors using numerical operations over using string operations. In general it is true that string assignments take a relatively long time.
The code first converts the ASCII code to uppercase so as to simplify the `IF` from

```
IF (ascii% >= 65 AND ascii% <= 90) or (ascii% >=97 and ascii% <=122) THEN
```

to

```
ucase% = ascii% AND &HDF
IF ucase% >= 65 AND ucase% <= 90 THEN
```

Comment: You went to a lot of effort to try to educate someone who probably either didn't pay attention in class or didn't read his assignment, but it's your time.  I doubt the OP even read past your first solution.